# adding to a value in a database not replacing it

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

So i am storing my users 'freinds' in a database and i am currently using this to add there freind to it

```
socket.on('addFreind', function(username, freind) {
    console.log("ADD FREIND " + freind + "TO " + username)

    let query = 'update users set freinds="' + freind + '" where username = "' + username + '"';
    connection.query(query, function(err) {
        console.log(err)
    });
});
```

but that just replaces the original value with the new one how can i add to the original value

i have tried querying the original value and adding it to an array and then adding the new value to that array then putting it in my database but that failed horribly and i was wondering if there was just a simple way to do this

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

Comment: i don't understand so were do i put concat or whatever in the query

Comment: `"UPDATE users SET friends = CONCAT(friends, '" + friend + "')...`. That being said, it sounds like you're storing multiple values in a single column. You should instead use a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: a one-to-many relationship what is that

Comment: Literally Google *"one-to-many relationship"*

Comment: sorry i am new to mysql

Comment: @NicholasHendricks: it would be well worth some time learning some relational database aspects, so that you **don't** use a table like a bad spreadsheet, and then have to [re]learn how it should have been done from the start. Don't worry, we've all been where you are at one time or another. Welcome to SO!